# Delete row or column issue (formula adjustment not done on these operations)

Tags: javascript, handsontable

handsontable.formula.js issue (not handsontable issue):

On removing row and column, handsontable is running hooks "afterRemoveRow" and "afterRemoveCol" but same hooks are not handled in handsontable.formula.js. Hence no formula adjustment on remove row and column.

(Note: There should be hooks entry for above twos like we have for afterCreateRow(), afterCreateCol() etc. you can see formula adjustment on create row and column).

Comment: anyone ?     Thanks, Atul

Comment: We'd probably need to see some code to understand the problem you're having.

Comment: @Atul.  I have just started using **handsontable**.  You are quite correct --- `handsontable.formula.js` needs an `afterRemoveRow/Col()` similar-ish to `afterCreateRow/Col()`, and presently does not adjust formulas after row/column delete.  For the moment I am managing without.  If I ever decide to write them, along the lines of the `afterCreate`s which are there, I will return here.